# Pass variables between QWizardPages

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

In my application I am creating a wizard. My first page contains a list of input files in QTextEdit , stored in QStringList.I want this QstringList to pass as variable to the next page .How can this be achieved? I have tried calling in constructor and by signals and slots but this is not working.

Comment: Some code fragments may help people see what you've tried and form better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try having the containing class of all your pages be the owner of the `QStringList`. Then, pass a reference to the `QStringList` to each page that needs it.